# How to Set FTP as SVN server repository path

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have external hosting but I think it didn't support installing SVN server application, I installed on my local computer Visual SVN server, and tried to set it's repository as ftp path, The application did't support network ftp, I tried to map ftp path to drive letter but didn't succeeded.
 Please Help 
[image]

Comment: That needs to be a windows path, not an URL. Even if you got this to work, your Subversion server would be on your machine and not at that network address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can not use non-local path as repository location
- Mounting remote location and using it as local repository-drive is, in common, **Bad Idea (tm)** and shortest way to corrupted repository

Correct solution in your case will be:

- **Local** repository
- **Local** Working Copy
- *Some* deploy-tools, which can work from post-commit hook (or on demand) and upload (using FTP) files on final destination